# Elliptic curve over finite non-prime fields

Tags: finite-fields, elliptic-curves

I have a problem understanding elliptic curves over finite non-prime fields, i.e., $E / {\Bbb F}_{p^k}$, where $p$ is prime and $k > 1$. Let's say we have a defining Weierstrass equation of the form $$E:\quad y^2 = x^3 + a x + b. $$
In my opinion, this then means that $a,b,x,y$ are all taken from the field the elliptic curve is defined over, i.e., $a,b,x,y \in \Bbb F_{p^k}$. Is this correct?

If so, how are then $a,b$ represented in a concrete case? If we take for instance $\Bbb F_{5^2}$ then, in my opinion, we can represent the field elements as $$\Bbb F_{5^2} = \{0,
 t,
 t + 3,
 4t + 3,
 2t + 2,
 4t + 1,
 2,
 2t,
 2t + 1,
 3t + 1,
 4t + 4,
 3t + 2,
 4,
 4t,
 4t + 2,
 t + 2,
 3t + 3,
 t + 4,
 3,
 3t,
 3t + 4,
 2t + 4,
 t + 1,
 2t + 3,
 1\}
$$
with the irreducible polynomial $p(t) := t^2 + 4t + 2$ and compute in this field accordingly. But this would mean that it is reasonable to consider e.g. the concrete elliptic curve, $$E_{(\Bbb F_{5^2}, t+3, 4t+4)}: \quad y^2 = x^3 + (t+3) x + (4t+4).$$
In order to test whether this is indeed an elliptic curve, I would then test the discriminant $\Delta := 4 a^3 + 27 b^2 \neq 0$ over this field and for $a:=t+3$, $b:=4t+4$. And similarly, if I want to test for supersingularity, I could e.g. use the Hasse invariant and test if the coefficient $c_{p-1}$ of the summand of $x^{p-1}$ in the polynomial $f(x)^{(p-1)/2}$, where $f(x) = x^3 + (t+3)x + (4t+4)$, is zero.
Actually, I can do all these computations in SageMath. What I don't understand is, why I don't find any such things in books or papers. There are even in the general case of elliptic curves over non-prime fields $\Bbb F_{p^k}$, $k > 1$, only curves with integer coefficients, like $y^2 = x^3 + 31x + 4$. (I do understand that a multiple $31x$ makes sense also in $\Bbb F_{p^k}$.)

Why is this so? Aren't these curves then actually always just in the base fields? What about the other cases?

Comment: I don't think mixing $X$s and $x$s is a good idea here; I'd choose a completely different letter to use for the generator of $\Bbb F_{25}$ here.

Comment: Also, please write $3X$ etc. instead of $3*X$. As it stands, it is impossible to read.

Comment: You have not fully specified your representation of $\Bbb F_{5^2}$ $-$ you also need an irreducible polynomial over $\Bbb F_5$ of order $2$, so that you can multiply and divide elements.

Comment: But to answer your question, I think people use such examples just to keep the arithmetic simple. You certainly don't need all the coefficients to be in the base field.

Comment: Ok, thanks. I've added the irreducible polynomial and changed the $X$ to $t$.

Comment: And I've also replaced "A" by "a" and "B" by "b" in the expression for the discriminant.

Comment: I don't see what the problem is. May be you just haven't met many elliptic curves defined over a field other than a prime field? For example, in cryptography they do use curves defined over $\Bbb{F}_{2^m}$ with [$m\in\{163,233,283,409,571\}$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elliptic-curve_cryptography#Applications).

Comment: Some books may prefer to use curves defined over a prime field as examples for pedagogical reason. For example, when explaining some properties of the $\zeta$-function you need to look at a curve over a field and its extension field. For the purposes of ease of presentation both those fields need to be relatively small, and this is forces the hand of the teacher (been there).

Comment: @Jyrki : Thanks for your reply. I am particularly looking at supersingular elliptic curves over $\Bbb F_{p^2}$ like in cryptography. Can you point me at a book or research paper, where they explicitely work in a non-prime field? That's exactly what my question is about: Why are many talking about the non-prime field cases, but are then avoiding them when concretely working? So, there aren't any other reasons than just pedagocial ones? (Which is odd for research papers) This is what confuses me. I would expect seeing many coefficients represented as I've indicated.

Comment: The entire of chapter 5 of Silverman deals with such cases. I'm not so familiar with Silverman-Tate, but I'm sure they do too. Maybe Washington's book will even have an example in the non-prime case. I agree with everyone that the reason that you won't have seen an example is merely because they are a pain to work with and you don't get any real further insight. Of course, they appear in papers all the time, but the treatment will hardly be as an example.

Comment: I agree with @Mummytheturkey. I learned nearly everything I know about elliptic curves from Silverman. I'm afraid the crypto side references I know of are quite dated (Menezes?) for I haven't been needed there for a decade or so.

Comment: Silverman (both the standard text and the "advanced" one) does not explicitly cover the non-prime field cases, apart of stating results that hold for all orders $q$. Silverman-Tate has not this focus, and Washington does not go specifically into the non-prime case either. Actually Lidl and Niederreiter do at some points also explicitely discuss non-prime cases. Btw., I do not blame any of these authors of these great books of not doing so. I was really just confused why the much larger (and I think very interesting) part has put aside (even in research papers).

Comment: Also, I don't think that finite non-prime fields are that "complicatied" that we should ignore them. I find them very beautiful and very interesting. Particularly because they go beyond high school mathematics of computing in the reals and modulo a prime (and maybe the complex numbers). There is much more insights into finite fields than with just considering the finite prime fields.